# Sum up tuples that contain a specified ID

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following set of information:

```
r-Id         v-id      cost
---------------------------
i-1234    v-1234       0.5
v-1234       -         1.25
```

I can't quite put my finger on a query for a scenario like this: If a `r-Id` consists of a `v-id`, sum up the corresponding `v-id` cost to the `r-id`.

So `i-1234` cost should be `cost: 1.75`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.r_id, max(t.cost) + coalesce(sum(t2.cost), 0)
from table t left join
     table t2
     on t.v_id = t2.r_id
group by t.r_id;
```

This produces the output you want for the data provided.  If the `r_id` ("i-1234") could be repeated multiple times, then this is not quite the right query.

EDIT:

If the `r_id` could appear multiple times, then you need to pre-aggregate by it:

```
select t.r_id, sumcost + coalesce(sum(t2.cost), 0)
from (select t.r_id, sum(t.cost) as sumcost
      from table t
      group by t.r_id
     ) t left join
     table t2
     on t.v_id = t2.r_id
group by t.r_id, sumcost,
```

Comment: Yes, the `r_id` can be repeated multiple times. Thanks for the help though. This is quite useful.